# Force HTTPs with .htaccess - "page isn't redirecting properly"

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect, mod-rewrite

I found this code to redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS.

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://my-domain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Works fine locally, but on live causes a browser error - "this page isn't redirecting properly."

I also get the same problem with this code instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? This is a CodeIgniter site, incidentally.

[EDIT - entire file (minus attempt to force https)]

```
RewriteEngine on

#favour naked domain over www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%1/$1 [R=301,NE,L]

#imgs from Desyn
RewriteRule ^vstk_file\/([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)/(.+) vstk_file.php?store=$1&item=$2&file=$3

#ditch CI index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

#route CSS files through PHP proxy to insert colour vars
RewriteRule (subj-(\w{11})\/)?([^\/]+)\.css$ assets/css/proxy.php?file=$3&subj-id=$2
```

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache.

Comment: Yeah I've done that quite a lot.

Comment: Can you post the entire .htaccess file, another rule may be conflicting.

Comment: See edit.......

Comment: In second block try without equal sign i.e. `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on`.